# Subscribe function not covered in code coverage jasmine - Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have written unit test cases using karma and jasmine ,everything works fine except whatever code written inside the subscribe block is not covered in code coverage.

component.ts function which is testing.

```
updateDocType(uRec, rType) {
    console.log(uRec)
    const obj = {
      vendor_mapping_list: uRec
    };
    const remainingItems = [];
    const executedItems = [];
    this.destroySearch$ = this.apiServ.cloneSubscribe();
    this.recordStatusMsg = 'Saving record';
    this.apiServ.awsPost('api_URL', obj)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySearch$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.status_code === '200') {
          this.recordStatusMsg = 'Record saved';
          const clearIt = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isToBeMappedEditMode = false;
            this.isMappedEditMode = false;
            this.recordStatusMsg = 'Viewing record';
            clearTimeout(clearIt);
          }, 1000);
          this.isChangeInData = true;
          if (rType === 'to_be_mapped') {
            this.dataMaintenanceGrid.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((rowNode, index) => {
              if (rowNode.data.isUpdated) {
                executedItems.push(rowNode.data);
              } else {
                remainingItems.push(rowNode.data);
              }
            });
            this.originalMaintenanceData = remainingItems;
            this.maintenanceData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalMaintenanceData));
            this.dataMaintenanceGrid.api.updateRowData(this.maintenanceData);
 
            executedItems.map(o => {
              o.isUpdated = false;
              this.originalmappedDocTypeData.push(o);
            });
            this.mappedDocTypeData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalmappedDocTypeData));
            this.mappedVendorGrid.api.updateRowData(this.mappedDocTypeData);
            this.defaultColEditDef = false;
            this.isToBeMappedItemChanged = false;
            this.isToBeMappedMultiRowSelected = false;
          } else {
            this.mappedDocTypeData.map(r => {
              if (r.isUpdated) {
                r.isUpdated = false;
              }
            });
            this.originalmappedDocTypeData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mappedDocTypeData));
            this.mappedVendorGrid.api.setRowData(this.mappedDocTypeData);
            this.defaultColEditMappedVenDef = false;
            this.isMappedItemChanged = false;
          }
        }
 
      });
  }
```

spec.ts file unit test code

```
it('updateDocType calling', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      // apiService.awsPost.and.returnValue(of({
      //   status_code: "200",
      //   response: []
      // }))
      // const source: Array<Observable<any>> = [of([{ status_code: '200', response: mappedStub }]), of([{ status_code: '200', response: mappedStub }])];
      spyOn(apiService, 'awsGet').and.returnValue(of({
        status_code: "200",
        response: []
      }));
      component.updateDocType([], 'to_be_mapped');
      tick();
      const res={
        status_code: "200",
        response: []
      };
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(true).toBeTrue();
        flush();
      });

      flush();
    })
    tick(2000)
  }));
```

Problem statement:Everything works fine test cases executed properly but whatever code written inside the subscribe block that will not added in code coverage.

> Its showing function not covered.

[image]

Comment: You are spying `awsGet`, but in the code it shows `awsPost`. That might be the issue.

Comment: I'll post the comment in the answers this way you can accept the answer so it is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spying `awsGet`, but in the code it shows `awsPost`.